# Simplifying retrieval of displayName and description fields from myJoinedTeams using Graph SDK in C#

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

```
IUserJoinedTeamsCollectionPage myJoinedTeams = await graphClient.Me.JoinedTeams.Request().Select("Id,DisplayName,Description").GetAsync();

if (myJoinedTeams != null && myJoinedTeams.Count > 0)
{
    var teams = await GetNextPages(myJoinedTeams);
    var resultSet = teams.Select(t => new MyTeam
    {
        Id = t.Id,
        DisplayName = t.AdditionalData["displayName"]?.ToString(),
        Description = t.AdditionalData["description"]?.ToString(),
    }).ToList();

    
}
```

How can the displayName and description fields be easily obtained from the myJoinedTeams collection using the Graph SDK in C#? Is there a simpler way to accomplish this without relying on the **AdditionalData** dictionary?

I am looking a way like

```
 t.DisplayName , t.Description
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of SDK do you use? For SDK v4 I see that Microsoft.Graph.Team has DisplayName property. So, no error when using `foreach (var team in myJoinedTeams) { var displayName = team.DisplayName; }`

Comment: SDK version 3.1.2

Comment: Is there any blocker for updating from v3 to v4? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v4.md